# How can I create this custom shadow?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create this:

[screenshot](http://addelement.com/single-card.png)

The screenshot shows a UI element that looks like a card, and it has a curved shadow underneath it. I'm not sure what the best way to create the shadow is. If anyone has implemented something similar, your insight would be much appreciated.

Here's an initial layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/card"
    style="@style/card"> <!-- contains the card drawable -->

    <TextView
        android:text="Text and images go here" />

</RelativeLayout>   

<ImageView 
    android:background="card_shadow" />
```

How would you go about doing this?  Could the shadow be included in the card drawable somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a RelativeLayout that contains a RelativeLayout with padding. The inner layout contains the actual view and the following background:

[image: drop_shadow_dark]

or for light themes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a 9patch would work fine here:
[image]

Comment: Woops. @Michael beat me there.